# Visio 2016 add template page to existing

Tags: ms-office, visio, visio2013, visio-2010

In Visio I can create template drawings(`*.vstx`) and I can also add more pages to a drawing (`*.vsdx`).

When I try to insert a template as a page into my existing drawing it opens as a totally new drawing and not as a page as I want. It seems I can only add blank pages to my existing drawing?

Anyone know any working solution on this or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A template is a file to start from, not a single page to insert in another document.
Usually people insert shapes in a page, not pages on a document.
What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have different templates containing printersettings, drawing heads etc and instead of creating one file for each page I want to insert a template as one page, so the drawing heads etc always are the same regardless of page size etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool [VisioSuperUtilities](http://www.sandrila.co.uk/visio-utilities/) by [Paul Herber](http://www.paulherber.co.uk/hire-me.php)
[image: Picture: VisioSuperUtilities insert Pages]
Or write your own code for do it.

Comment: Thank you. That was a good one but I'll see if there is any other way of solving this than paying for a tool :)

Comment: You can write your own code of course, but in this case you spend a lot of time! Two years ago in Russian visio forum we have same topic ([read via Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ru&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fvisio.getbb.ru%2Fviewtopic.php%3Ff%3D6%26t%3D1049)). You can find there codes which can help you for create your own solution!